# Interactive Data Language - Array manipulation

Tags: idl-programming-language

I have two arrays of the same length in IDL. I want to combine the two arrays pairwise so that I can then print the two arrays as columns to file. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine two arrays (with same length **n**) like this :

```
combined = [[array1], [array2]]
```

so that `combined` is n x 2.

Although you can write your data without creating a third array:

```
openw, lun, 'path_to_file.ext', /get_lun
foreach elem, array1, index do begin
  printf, lun, elem, array2[index]
endforeach
free_lun, lun
```

Comment: I managed to solve the problem doing something like you suggest yesterday. Thanks for the answer anyhow.

Comment: The use of `foreach` assumes >= IDL 8.0.